# Variable based on active makefile target (outside rule)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got a build configuration that looks something like this:

Makefile:

```
build-for-x: X := yes
build-for-x: all

build-for-y: Y := yes
build-for-y: all

SRC :=
include foo.mk
include bar.mk

all: # ... some targets which use SRC eventually
```

foo.mk:

```
ifeq ($(X),yes)
    SRC += foo_x.c
endif
ifeq ($(Y),yes)
    SRC += foo_y.c
endif
```

bar.mk:

```
ifeq ($(X),yes)
    SRC += bar_x.c
endif
ifeq ($(Y),yes)
    SRC += bar_y.c
endif
```

This is obviously highly simplified. What I'm actually doing is building the same codebase for two different embedded platforms, with many different modularized sections (foo and bar here) and several variables for source, include, tests, etc.

The above doesn't work, because X or Y are only set within the targets which build-for-x/build-for-y have as prerequisites. The code within foo.mk/bar.mk is evaluated beforehand, when neither variable is set.

Is there a good way to handle situations like this? What's a sane way I might restructure my build configuration to:

- Preserve the modularity (foo.mk/bar.mk are separate files)
- Allow one to run `make build-for-x`/`make build-for-y` to build the separate implementations

I want to avoid making foo.mk look something like:

```
build-for-x: SRC += foo_x.c
build-for-y: SRC += foo_y.c
```

unless I absolutely have to, since this forces me to have a dependency on a particular target. I would much rather keep all the target-dependent assignments at the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

Makefile:

```
build-for-x: SRC := SRC_X
build-for-x: all

build-for-y: SRC := SRC_Y
build-for-y: all
```

foo.mk:

```
SRC_X += foo.x_c
SRC_Y += foo.y_c
```

bar.mk:

```
SRC_X += bar.x_c
SRC_Y += bar.y_c
```

Comment: That'll do. Thanks!